# Using couchbase as memcache in a cluster configuration

Tags: python, django, memcached, couchbase, high-availability

I've got a couchbase cluster that also serves as a 'drop-in' replacement for memcached in my Django-based production environment.

In other words: in my django configuration I provided one of my couchbase nodes as the 'Location' for the memcache service.

This works well - but creates a single point of failure: what if that node I provided goes down?

I suppose I could provide a virtual IP/FQDN that would round-robin to each of the nodes in my CB cluster, but I'm hoping there's a better solution? something built into Django, perhaps?

It appears that if I provide a list of "Location"s, django would simply shard the keys over all the locations - which would not solve my problem.

Comment: Django sharding the connections wouldn't cause write issues, the orchestrator node of your couchbase cluster would still shard independent of which node receives the request. With regards to Django reading the cache in a failover scenario, it's less clear however. Couchbase could serve replicas providing a remaining node was read, but the [Django backend](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py) isn't clear in how it determines which location to use (in my quick skim of it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution would be to use [Couchbase's MOXI server](http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/downloads#Moxi_Server) to proxy memcached. You install it on your application server and it will do the connections to the Couchbase cluster for you. In Moxi's configs you want to make sure that you are using at least 3 of the Couchbase cluster nodes. In the Couchbase cluster, make sure you are using Couchbase buckets.

Comment: This sounds very promising. Thanks!

Comment: Finally gotten around to testing this - this is just what I needed. Thanks Kirk!